# C# get, set properties

Tags: c#, properties, get, set

I have the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 myClass = new Class1("ttt");
        myClass.Name = "xxx";
        MessageBox.Show(myClass.Name);
    }
```

and

```
class Class1
{
    string str = "";

    public Class1(string name)   
    {
        str = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return str; }
        set;

    }
}
```

Initially I set:

```
  myClass.Name = "ccc";
```

but later changed it to:

```
  myClass.Name = "xxx";
```

and also changed:

```
  set {str = value;}
```

to:

```
  set;
```

Why when I run it do I get "ccc" instead of "xxx" ?

In my current code there is "ccc".

Comment: It's very confusing showing the changes. Just post what your current code is - ideally as a short but *complete* program.

Comment: And this code actually compiles???

Comment: `set;` has no action associated with it. It does nothing. `{str = value;}` is the part that actually **sets** your property. Undeletable.

Comment: fix your compile errors. Your IDE probably asked you if you want to run the last known working configuration. Fix the compile errors as I suggested below

Answer (score 4):

```
public string Name
{
    get { return str; }
    set;

}
```

should be

```
public string Name
{
    get { return str; }
    set { str = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Name` property as follows:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return str; }
    set { str = value; }
}
```

To **answer** your question, the reason why you get "ccc" instead of "xxx" is that you have compile errors. When you run your application it will ask you if you want to run the latest known working configuration. The last time your program did compile, you used "ccc" as literal, and that is what is still running.

Fix the compile errors and run it again, and then it will be "xxx"

Answer (score 1):

The pattern

```
public string Name {get;set;}
```

is what is called "Auto-Implemented Properties".

The compilier creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

What you original code seems to be doing is get on a field you defined but a set on the anonymous backing field. Therefore build error ...